# How to undo card archive on Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I accidentally hit `c` with a card selected and archived the card. I tried to undo the archive but couldn't find the option. I tried moving the card back to the list but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In the top right select `Show menu`

[image: Show menu]

Then click `More`

[image: More]

Then click `Archived Items`

[image: Archived Items]

You then click the `Send to Board` button on the item and it will be reinstated to your board.

[image: Send to Board]

Comment: Updated my answer for the new UI

Answer (score 2):

You can also visit your profile and see the audit trail of what you've done to each card, which includes a link to the archived card. Then you can "move" the card back to the board.

Answer (score 2):

Click `< Show Sidebar` then `Menu` then `Archive` to see your archived items. Once there you can add them back to your board.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no longer a Show Sidebar menu in Trello

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in the card menu, counter-intuitively named "send to board"
[image: Screenshot]

There is a discussion for android app: this option seems to be named something like "unarchive", which is inconsistent but easier to understand. Stay tuned for modifications.

Comment: I found no keyboard shortcut for that function. It's probably not frequent enough for them to care

Comment: If you can't find the card you have archived though (since when you archive it the card is no longer on the board) you can find it in your profile activity as per other answer.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to no longer be an Archived Items menu item on the board's menu. I was only able to find an archived card by searching for it.

[image: Board Menu is missing Archived Items]